# Use join statement, but if table is empty

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

When create a query, I want to use `join` twice like the following:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('members');
$this->db->join('members_group', 'members_group.mgid = members.mgid');
$this->db->join('members_profiles','members_profiles.mid = members.mid');
$this->db->where('members.mid=' . $id);
$this->db->get()
```

The problem in the `join` statement number 2, If there is no data within the `members_profiles` table, the query return empty array. but if I remove the `join` statement number 2, the result will be correct data.

**How can I make the query return data whether** `members_profiles` **table contains of data that related to a member or not**?

Comment: Maybe use a Left join?

Comment: @John Ruddell: I don't change anything, this is the default form of join statement.

Comment: yea I know that. what im saying is you need to change your join to a left join. or else it will filter out all the rows

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Thank you, I did it, but if there is no data related to the target member, the `members.mid` column returns empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Codeigniter allows variant join types to be specified in the third parameter of the `join()` method.

Try this:

```
 $this->db->join('members_profiles','members_profiles.mid = members.mid', 'left');
```

An ordinary (inner) join suppresses records from the first (left-hand) table that don't match the second (right-hand) table. A left join preserves records on the left that don't match records on the right. It places NULL values in the columns of the resultset that should have come from the missing right-hand table.  This does exactly what you want.

Comment: check A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins by Jeff Atwood: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thank you, but there is a small problem,  the `mid` column returns empty if there is no data related to that member in `members_profiles` table.

Comment: @LionKing Than try a full outer join so you get all rows from both the left and the right tables?

Comment: Hmmm.  no full outer join implemented in MySQL. Notorious pain in the neck to implement with a bunch of left / right joins and unions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('members');
$this->db->join('members_group', 'members_group.mgid = members.mgid');
$this->db->join('members_profiles','members_profiles.mid = members.mid','left');
$this->db->where('members.mid=' . $id);
$this->db->get()
```